# Flag declined for disparaging remarks - mod comments inadvertently directed at me

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445736/visual-studio-online-deployment-tf400324-errorsystem-exception-conflict-web) I alerted the OP that disparaging comments were inappropriate, and that I edited them out. The OP had made remarks about tech support + Indians.

After I edited out further content on the OP's self-posted answer, they got upset with me, told me to "*Please keep away from my questions as u shown u don't understand issues*" and requested deletion of their account. At this point, I flagged the original question, so that there would be clarity as to why this deletion request was occurring, and why the edits had taken place.

In the flag, I said:

> Just wanted to make sure, before you delete his account, you saw why he requested deletion: I called him out for making inappropriate comments (both in questions and comments) - such as the comment about Indians + tech support that I edited out. I didn't flag him for moderator attention earlier (maybe I should have) - but he seems to think his behavior has been just fine and that it's me that's the problem.

Oddly, my flag was declined, but based on the moderator's explanation, it appears whoever reviewed my flag thought I was the OP:

> declined - Your line about Indians was completely inappropriate and
>   should never have existed in the first place. A user pointing that out
>   is not offensive.

I believe my flag and related comments were misunderstood, as I was not the one who made the remarks. I was the "user pointing that out."

Comment: Maybe your custom comment wasn't as clear as it could be.  Oh well, comments were cleaned-up anyway and it doesn't seem likely the OP will be back any time soon.  It isn't exactly clear why you posted this, are you fishing for an explicit apology from the moderator?

Comment: @HansPassant - I need no apology. But I also have no desire to have someone thinking I'm making those types of comments. I don't need that as part of my history here.

Comment: While I wasn't the mod to handle the flags on that post I'd like to reassure you that the history is very clear that you took the right action and that it wasn't you that was making such a statement - you were the one trying to clear it up - many thanks for that. It looks to me that the response you received was  actually directed to the OP and not yourself... Not quite sure how that happened, but it clearly wasn't intended - so apologies for that. A declined flag is no big deal (although annoying) but importantly - your reputation is certainly not tarnished so please don't worry about that.

Comment: @JonClements thank you. And it certainly did appear the comments were directed toward the OP. Which makes me wonder if the OP also raised a flag...

Comment: @JonClements According to [this post on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37345/should-moderators-be-able-to-see-who-flags-a-comment), mods don't know who flagged. Is that still true?

Comment: @Laurel it's recently been made possible in a round-about way...

Comment: @JonClements [Like this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280681/323179)

Comment: @Laurel yeah - was trying to find that :)

Comment: As a note, you weren't alone on this: A bot over at [SOCVFinder](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/socvfinder) caught the heat from the comments and notified a couple users, we did cast a good amount of flags on the various inappropriate comments.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

That was my fault. The combination of flag on the post and comment caused me to misread and think that it was just the user complaining about *you*. You definitely did nothing wrong and the comment was aimed at the other user I thought was flagging.

But rest assured, your information was seen. Users frequently complain about a specific post when requesting deletion already, so we tend to see what actually happened.

Comment: *animuson opens ticked: usability bug*

Comment: Appreciate the response - I figured it was something like this. Good to know we're all on the same page... :)